# How to give output of a java script variable in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a javascript variable "len" and I want its value in my button ,here is my button code :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
   Pending Task
   <span class="badge badge-light"></span>
   <span class="sr-only"></span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: *I want its value in my button*, what does this mean? What is *Pending Task*? should that `len` value appear in `span` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I suggest to add another `<span>` to make the text of your button addressable without changing the icons. So your button becomes

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
   <span class="content">Pending Task</span>
   <span class="badge badge-light"></span>
   <span class="sr-only"></span> 
</button>
```

Then in your JavaScript, you need a selector to address this new `<span>`. Currently you button has no ID, so the following selector might also select other buttons. As you're already using bootstrap, you'll have jQuery available. That makes the code for setting the text rather short:

```
 $( 'nav button .content' ).text( len );
```

---

As you're just using vanilla JS right now, the above line could also be rewritten like this

```
 document.querySelector( 'nav button .content' ).textContent = len;
```

Comment: Hey!, its not working  can you please help me I am new in devolping .

Comment: Can you define "not working"  in a little more detail?

Comment: I think you have not added jquery to your code and that's why it's not working for you.

Comment: @elahekarami Bootstrap has jQuery included, so this should not be the issue here.

Comment: I have include your code in my app.js file but not getting its value in button however if I do console.log of variable (just for confirming the variable value), it has a value

Comment: What value do you see in the console? Some simple type like string or number or an object of some sort?

Comment: you can check here :- https://taskm.netlify.app/ ,for code :-https://github.com/hardikchoudhary20/TaskM, if possible pls also review m site ,it is my first project

Comment: From a quick test in the console, it seems to work just fine. Just add the respective row at the end of your `addtask()` function and I see no reason for it to fail. PS: you may want to have a look at ESLint to improve your code's readability and enforce a particular code style.

Comment: hey! thanks. I will definately continue with it and thanks for your time.